# Accessing control register of parallel port using inpout32 windows7(64bit)

Tags: python, windows, parallel-port

I have a brainvision USB adapter that has a trigger port connecting to DB25 cable. The other end of the cable goes into the parallel port of PC and has a BNC cable connected to it. I checked for the connectivity to the pins of DB25 cable and it seems to be connected(most likely NOT) to the Line Feed pin (Pin 14) of parallel port. Now I am using the inpout32 library to write to the data pins of the parallel port in python that sends triggers to the brainvision recorder(for EEG) from my presentation software on the PC. I want to send triggers to another system (which accepts TTL pulse trigger) using the BNC cable. Can anybody please suggest me a way to do it?

I know the question suggests the use of inpout32 library, but I am open to solutions.

Some things I have already tried out:-

1. Tried to install the pyparallel library on my system but it gives me an error in the import statement(a dll error). Tried fixing it with no luck because giveio does not get installed on my system. Searched it through the internet. Seems to be a problem of 64-bit system(runs good on 32-bit).
2. Presently generating keypresses from python as the system recorder has an option of manual recorder using keypress. But it needs me to shift the focus to the recorder window to record triggers. I know it can be done automatically too using python but it causes a significant delay.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR:

1. It could be that what you are trying to achieve is not possible with your cable (i.e., it can only be used as an "input" and not as an output)
2. In your situation I would contact the Brain Products customer support, because your problem is hardware related and it will be hard for somebody to give helpful answers to your problem if they cannot replicate it

---

I am a bit familiar with the hardware you are using so let us clarify: Are you using a cable like this (see image)?

[image: Parallel Port + BNC Cable]

We are also using this cable - however in the opposite way that you intend. We connect the male BNC plug to a response button box. Whenever a button on that box is pressed, a TTL trigger is sent via the BNC cable to the db25 connector (with the red tape in the image) and goes then directly into the Brain Products hardware, showing up as a trigger in the BrainVision Recorder software.

For me it was very counter intuitive that the TTL triggers first go to that end of the db25 connector cable that is plugged into the computer rather than directly into the Brain Products hardware (which records all triggers and data). However, the customer support told me that this is the way to go.